# How to create multiple sub element under a root element in XML using python?

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I am trying to create a simple XML file using python3 with the following output.

```
<products>
    <product>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Apple</name>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Banana</name>
    </product>
</products>
```

I went through the xml.etree.ElementTree however i couldnot find the exact way to complete as  above

I could achieve something like this

```
<products>
    <product>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Apple</name>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Banana</name>
    </product>
</products>
```

The following is my code i used:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
root = ET.Element("products")
doc = ET.SubElement(root, "product")

ET.SubElement(doc, "id").text = "some value1"
ET.SubElement(doc, "name").text = "some vlaue1"

ET.SubElement(doc, "id").text = "some value2"
ET.SubElement(doc, "name").text = "some vlaue2"
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("filename.xml")
```

I want to create different product sub element under the root products.
Any suggestion on how to accomplish this will be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument of `SubElement` is the tag to which you append the newly created element. In your example all `id` and `name` elements are appended to the first `product` you created - `doc`.

Try creating a second one the same way and appending to that one, i.e. add

```
doc2 = ET.SubElement(root, "product")
```

and switch `doc2` for `doc` in your second set of product details.

Comment: Your answer helped me. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

if position of insertion is needed use insert

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element,SubElement,Comment,tostring
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

root = Element("products")
first = Element("product")
SubElement(first,"id").text="1"
SubElement(first,"name").text="Apple"

second = Element("product")
SubElement(second,"id").text="2"
SubElement(second,"name").text="Banana"
root.insert(1,first)
root.insert(2,second)
print(parseString(tostring(root,'utf-8')).toprettyxml(indent=" "))
```

Answer (score 1):

I know its been answered long back, however, my solution might help people who is looking for complete solution.

Below script reads an xml and add on 2 new tags with text.

```
import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


# Tags to be added
stringsToAddAsText = ('new1', 'new2') 

# Element name
tag = 'InstallationInclude' 

# Sub element name
subTag = 'IS_NEW'

# getting the File name as runtime argument
fileName = sys.argv[1]

# Passing the path of the xml document to enable the parsing process
tree = ET.parse(fileName)
 
# getting the parent tag of the xml document
root = tree.getroot()
 
# printing the root (parent) tag
# of the xml document, along with
# its memory location
print(root)


# add new elements 
child = ET.Element(tag)
schild = ET.SubElement(child, subTag)
schild.text = stringsToAddAsText[0]
child1 = ET.Element(tag)
schild1 = ET.SubElement(child1, subTag)
schild1.text = stringsToAddAsText[1]                       
root.append(child)
root.append(child1)
       
ET.dump(root)
ET.indent(tree, space="\t", level=0)

# getting the output file name as a runtime argument and writes the updated file
tree.write(sys.argv[2], encoding="utf-8",xml_declaration=True)
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Installation InstallationVersion="1.0.0">  
    <InstallationInclude>
        <IS_NEW>new1</IS_NEW>
    </InstallationInclude>
    <InstallationInclude>
        <IS_NEW>new2</IS_NEW>
    </InstallationInclude>
</Installation>
```